# Which HTTP status should be returned when a SPECIFIC page will be down for several days

Tags: asp.net, http, seo, http-status-code-503

We are uploading a new version of our website.
For various reasons, some pages that exists on the older version still aren't ready for the new version and we need to temporarily take them off.

Which HTTP status should we return for these pages considered they will be up and running again within several days.

Is using `ServiceUnavailable = 503` only for these pages the right way or will it have negative impact on the entire website?

(Using ASP.NET in case it's related in some way...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [status code `503`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4) seems to be the best choice here:

> The 503 (Service Unavailable) status code indicates that the server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload or scheduled maintenance, which will likely be alleviated after some delay.

It shouldn’t be relevant that it’s not due to overload or maintenance in your case. What is relevant is that it’s your fault (hence a status code from the [`5xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6) class), and that it’s temporary (hence `503`), so there’s no need to let them know the real reason.

While `503` is typically used for the whole site, I can see no reason why it shouldn’t be used for specific pages only. A possible drawback: If a bot ‎successively crawls a few documents that give `503`, it might think that the whole site is affected and stop crawling for now.

If you know when the page will be available again, you can send the [`Retry-After` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.3):

> When sent with a 503 (Service Unavailable) response, Retry-After indicates how long the service is expected to be unavailable to the client.

(FWIW, the [Googlebot seems to support this](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/01/how-to-deal-with-planned-site-downtime.html).)

---

In the post [Website outages and blackouts the right way](https://plus.google.com/115984868678744352358/posts/Gas8vjZ5fmB) (by a Google employee at the time), my assumptions are confirmed as far as Google Search is concerned: `503` should also be used for specific pages only; crawling rate might be affected if Googlebot gets many `503` answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer unor! Since this is extremely risky, I need an official quote from Google it won't affect the rest of the website before using it (and accepting the answer). Thanks!

Comment: @gdoron: Which risk do you mean exactly?

Comment: Making Google think our entire website is down and make them remove us from their index. I want to make sure they understand it's only these pages.

Comment: @gdoron: Google doesn’t remove `503` URLs from the index (except maybe if you have them for a long time). The only thing that can happen is that they stop crawling more pages in that session; they will try to crawl again in the next session (hours or days later) though. But you’ll have this problem for any `5xx` status code, not just for `503`. As the post [Website outages and blackouts the right way](https://plus.google.com/115984868678744352358/posts/Gas8vjZ5fmB) (by a Google employee at the time) confirms, this can’t be prevented, and it’s the right way to handle it.

Comment: Thanks sir, that link was all the confirmation needed.
(Please add it to the answer as it's priceless...)